# Copying parent <li> content into another <ul> onclick?

Tags: javascript

On my website i have two lists. One is empty and one filled with some recipes. What I am trying to do is to make user able to add the recipe he likes into his favorites. Actually to copy selected into empty list by clicking on "like" button.

HTML

```html
<div id="myrecipes">
   <ul id="recipeList">
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="recipes">
 <ul>
   <li>
     <img src="trpeza.jpg" alt="">
       <p>recipe 1 <i onclick="like(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <img src="trpeza.jpg" alt="">
     <p>recipe 1 <i onclick="like(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></p>
   </li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

MY JS

```js
function like(x) {
    var emptyList = document.getElementById("recipeList");
    var listItem = x.parentNode;
        x.style.color = "green";
        listItem.appendChild(emptyList);
}
```

Also I would like to add some close button so he can easily remove it from favorites.

Comment: If you copy the `<li>`, do you realize that it will not be saved?

Comment: Yes i understand that, i guess i will need to add some php code into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below Code Snippet

```js
function like(x) {
  var emptyList = document.getElementById("recipeList");
  if (x.classList.contains("fa-thumbs-up")) {
   // For Copying to Favourite Recipes
    var listItem = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cln = listItem.cloneNode(true);
    var oAddedIcon = cln.querySelector(".fa-thumbs-up");
    oAddedIcon.classList.remove("fa-thumbs-up");
    oAddedIcon.classList.add("fa-thumbs-down");
    oAddedIcon.style.color = "red";
    x.style.color = "green";
    emptyList.appendChild(cln);
  } else if (x.classList.contains("fa-thumbs-down")) {
  // For deleting from Favourite Recipes
    x.classList.remove("fa-thumbs-down");
    x.classList.add("fa-thumbs-up");
    emptyList.removeChild(x.parentNode.parentNode);

  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="myrecipes">
  <h2>Favourite Recipes</h2>
  <ul id="recipeList">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="recipes">
  <h2>Recipes</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="trpeza.jpg" alt="Recipe Image 1">
      <p>recipe 1 <i onclick="like(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="trpeza.jpg" alt="Recipe Image 2">
      <p>recipe 2 <i onclick="like(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></p>
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```